# Relation between number of physical cores and VCores available on YARN?

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh

I am new to yarn and I am writing a YARN Application on Java. As per the requirement, **I can only use N number of physical cores on a machine**. YARN allows to set Number of VCores and Memory that I want to allocate to my application.
**Is it possible to determine number of VCores for given N number of physical cores?**

Eg. If I have 32 Physical Cores and I just want to use 8 physical cores, then what should be number of VCores for my application?

Answer (score 1):

use 8

> In almost all cases, a node’s virtual core capacity should be set as
>   the number of physical cores on the machine.

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/12/managing-multiple-resources-in-hadoop-2-with-yarn/

Comment: I case of my machine, Yarn shows maximum capability of 32 cores, and here is the output of lscpu on my machine Architecture:          
x86_64
CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit

Byte Order:  Little Endian

CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 60
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               3201.000
BogoMIPS:              6384.99
Virtualization:        VT-x


NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3

Comment: How many nodes do you have in your cluster??, Its clear from lscpu output that your machine has 4 cores.

Comment: What is value of yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores in yarn-site??

Answer (score 0):

Please note usually the number of containers assigned to the job is drieven by the memory usage (since that is the limiting factor).

However, if you have an incorrect vcore setting in yarn (for example if it is too small) then that will limit the processing power of the cluster.

The number vcores assigned to yarn can be calculated by multiplying the number of CPU by the number of cores per CPU, and described [here](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cdh_ig_yarn_tuning.html#step_1_worker_configuration)